# How to check if names of datatypes are the same

Tags: prolog

I wonder if there is a quick way to check whether 2 datatypes are the same.

Example - let's say I have a list like this:

> [odd(1), odd(3), even(2), odd(5), even(4)]

Now if I pull 2 elements from the list (index 0 and index 1) I want to know if they are both of the same data type or different (i.e. odd()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `X` and `Y` are pulled from the list, you can check literally,

```
X = odd(_), Y = odd(_) ; X = even(_), Y = even(_).
```

Or more generally, you can check...

```
functor(X, Functor, ArgCount),
functor(Y, Functor, ArgCount).
```

The above will succeed if `X` and `Y` have the same functor (`even` or `odd`, for example) and whether they have the same number of arguments. `functor/3` is an ISO Prolog predicate, so it works on any ISO compliant Prolog.

You can do a little test at the Prolog prompt that illustrates. Note that only successful results are when the "data types" of the chosen list members match.

```
| ?- List = [odd(1), odd(3), even(2), odd(5), even(4)], member(X, List), member(Y, List), functor(X, F, A), functor(Y, F, A).

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(1)
Y = odd(1) ? ;

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(1)
Y = odd(3) ? ;

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(1)
Y = odd(5) ? ;

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(3)
Y = odd(1) ? ;

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(3)
Y = odd(3) ? a

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(3)
Y = odd(5)

A = 1
F = even
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = even(2)
Y = even(2)

A = 1
F = even
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = even(2)
Y = even(4)

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(5)
Y = odd(1)

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(5)
Y = odd(3)

A = 1
F = odd
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = odd(5)
Y = odd(5)

A = 1
F = even
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = even(4)
Y = even(2)

A = 1
F = even
List = [odd(1),odd(3),even(2),odd(5),even(4)]
X = even(4)
Y = even(4)

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed